# How to force asp.net web api 2 to response xml without global config changed

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

My WebApiCongig use

```
    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
```

to force to response json.

But there are some specific api that need to return xml format data.

I use

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostNotify(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
  HttpResponseMessage resp = Request.CreateResponse<PackageModal>(HttpStatusCode.OK, value: package,
                        formatter: Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
                    return resp;
}
```

But it doesn't work. Still gets a json-format response.

Comment: What does your ajax call look like?

Comment: Does my answer help? If yes, please accept it. If not, please explain your question in more detail :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the accept-header in your request and the contentnegotiation will take care of the output format!